# ToDictionary() returns a nullable dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary from the `IdentityResult` `Errors` property which is an `IEnumerable<IdentityError>` like so:

```
var dictionary = result.Errors.ToDictionary(e => e.Code, e => e.Description);
```

For some reason `dictionary` is now a `Dictionary<string,string>?` I would like this to be `Dictionary<string,string>` (not nullable). Am I doing something stupidly here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation [Declaration statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/declarations#implicitly-typed-local-variables) :

> When var is used with nullable reference types enabled, it always implies a nullable reference type even if the expression type isn't nullable.

`ToDictionary` return a non nullable reference, but with `var` the variable is considered as nullable reference.

If you want force the variable to be non nullable reference, you need to declare the variable's type explicitly :

```cs
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = result.Errors.ToDictionary(e => e.Code, e => e.Description);
```

But it's rarely necessary. Even if the variable is nullable, if null is never affected in the variable, then the compiler don't warn if the variable isn't checked before to be used.

```cs
var dictionary = result.Errors.ToDictionary(e => e.Code, e => e.Description);
var type = dictionary.GetType(); //No warning
```

```cs
var dictionary = result.Errors.ToDictionary(e => e.Code, e => e.Description);
dic = null;
var type = dictionary.GetType(); //Warning CS8602 Dereference of a possibly null reference.
```

Comment: Why is this the case? It's so counter-intuitive.

Comment: @RhysvanderWaerden, I don't know, but this is a good question.

Comment: I actually found the answer in [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/119znda/c_var_with_a_reference_type_is_always_nullable/). The type is nullable but should be "not null here". Apparently this is because many users complained that they could not reassign the variable to null afterwards.